# regex lookahead confusion

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

```
let sampleWord = "mA11";
let match1 = /(?=\w{4,6})(?=\D\d{2})/;
let match2 = /(?=\w{4,6})/;
let match3 = /(?=\D\d{2})/;

console.log(match1.test(sampleWord));
console.log(match2.test(sampleWord));
console.log(match3.test(sampleWord));
```

Here's the console output:

```
// console output
false
true
true
```

Here's my regex code.
My confusion is the first part `/?=\w{4,6}/` This means a string of character 4 to 6.
and the second part `(?=\D\d{2})` This means anystring that has one non digit character in the beginning and two consecutive digits.
so How is `'mA11'` not matching `/(?=\w{4,6})(?=\D\d{2})/;`
it's of length 4 and a11 also satisfies the second condition.
And how is the `'mA111'` string matching the **match1** condition?
This also satisfies for strings more than length 6 which I don't know how?

Comment: `(?=\w{4,6})(?=\D\d{2})` means that you want the next 4 chars to be word chars, and *at the same time*, the next char must be a non-digit and the second and third ones must be digits. There is no such a substring in the input text. [Lookarounds "stand their ground".](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground)

Comment: Then how come **mA111** returns true?

Comment: `A111` matches your unanchored pattern. Anchor it (`/^(?=\w{4,6})(?=\D\d{2})/`), and there will be no match.

Comment: So why doesn't the unanchored match work in the case of `mA11`
Here it can also match `A11`
As the matching cursor stands in the first index and it checks mA1 in case of **mA11**
shouldn't it do the same for the case of **mA111** and try to match `mA1`
as the index stays in the first position always?

Comment: There is no way to match `A11`, you require at least 4 chars to appear immediately to the right of the current location in `(?=\w{4,6})`.